# How to run a pickle file in node js

Tags: javascript, python, node.js, artificial-intelligence, pickle

Working in an AI/ML project, I need a way to run the pickle file inside nodejs so I can use it to run the algorithm on the data they submitted.

Comment: as I know only Python uses `pickle` and other languages may not have function to read it. You may need to use other format - some ML modules may have some universal format which you can use in other ML modules.

Comment: if you need to work with some data then maybe keep it as CSV.

Comment: Would the [node-pickle](https://github.com/jlaine/node-jpickle) module work for you?

Answer (score 1):

Try to use the node-pickle library to convert the pickle file to the JSON object. [Here documentation of node-pickle](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-pickle)

```
const nodePickle = require('node-pickle');

// Convert pickled object to JSON object
nodePickle.load(pickledData)
.then(data => ({
// data is a JSON object here
})
```

Then you can use tensorflow.js to run that JSON object as a model.
[Tenrsorflow.js Documentation](https://www.tensorflow.org/js/guide/conversion)

Answer (score 0):

The only one I could find from a quick google search is [`node-jpickle`](https://github.com/jlaine/node-jpickle). According to it's docs, it seems to be able to handle most of the situations `pickle` can, even some of the more advanced ones such as classes:

```js
function MyClass() {}

var jpickle = require('jpickle');
jpickle.emulated['__main__.MyClass'] = MyClass;
var unpickled = jpickle.loads(pickled);
```

If you're just trying to pickle/unpickle, you can just do it like you would in Python:

```
var unpickled = jpickle.loads(pickled);
```

The docs don't state anything about a normal `load` function however.